# LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_83.lib'

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems, boost-filesystem

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_83.lib' Proiect IP test C:\Proiect IP test\Proiect IP test\Proiect IP test\LINK 1

This is the code I want to run:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

path myPath = ("C:\Visual Studio IP\Test Project");



void createFolder(path myPath) {
    if (!exists(myPath)) {
        perror("Path doesn't exist!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        create_directory(myPath);
        std::cout << "directory created in: " << myPath;
    }
}

int main() {
    

    return 0;
}
```

I opened boostrap.bat and ./b2 with all the commands for x64 architecture.I did all the steps to install but after installation when I try to run the program I have this error, I linked everything and did all the research.The exe installs all the libraries except this, `libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_83.lib`.

I am using Visual Studio 2022

Any idea please? I have been struggling with this error for 2 days